# calculate cosine similarity

Tags: java, jdbc

How can I calculate cosine similarity to complete my search engine project using jdbc.
I have table term frequency query to store input from user and table term frequency document to store all the information about document, I have done calculate query and document weighted.
the output after calculate cosine similarity is the display which document related to the query from user input.
I don't have any idea and I don't know how to calculate it because it involve table in database.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to query a table?  Please be more specific with your question and possibly include an example or two.

Comment: ok, user have to enter the query and the output that user get is from the data which is i have store in table document.i have table, tf_query and tf_doc, tf_query store data from user and tf_doc store data about document. i have done calculate the tf-idf and weighted and now i have to calculate the cosine similarity.

Comment: eg: user enter how are you? and the output is how are you dear that is store in table document 1 and document 2

Comment: means, calculate the similarity between query and document...

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to calculate the cosine similarity from a simple SELECT query, since the cosine similarity will involve matrix multiplication. You will need to SELECT all the documents that contain the query terms, extract their term vectors, and then do the multiplication at your application layer.

Comment: sorry, i'm not clear about the answer

Answer (score 1):

this is the program that calculates the cosine similaritu between 2 sentences I hope you can do the  changes you need to obtain what you want.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * 
* @author Xiao Ma
* mail : 409791952@qq.com
*`enter code here`
*/
  public class SimilarityUtil {

public static double consineTextSimilarity(String[] left, String[] right) {
    Map<String, Integer> leftWordCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> rightWordCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Integer temp = null;
    for (String leftWord : left) {
        temp = leftWordCountMap.get(leftWord);
        if (temp == null) {
            leftWordCountMap.put(leftWord, 1);
            uniqueSet.add(leftWord);
        } else {
            leftWordCountMap.put(leftWord, temp + 1);
        }
    }
    for (String rightWord : right) {
        temp = rightWordCountMap.get(rightWord);
        if (temp == null) {
            rightWordCountMap.put(rightWord, 1);
            uniqueSet.add(rightWord);
        } else {
            rightWordCountMap.put(rightWord, temp + 1);
        }
    }
    int[] leftVector = new int[uniqueSet.size()];
    int[] rightVector = new int[uniqueSet.size()];
    int index = 0;
    Integer tempCount = 0;
    for (String uniqueWord : uniqueSet) {
        tempCount = leftWordCountMap.get(uniqueWord);
        leftVector[index] = tempCount == null ? 0 : tempCount;
        tempCount = rightWordCountMap.get(uniqueWord);
        rightVector[index] = tempCount == null ? 0 : tempCount;
        index++;
    }
    return consineVectorSimilarity(leftVector, rightVector);
}

/**
 * The resulting similarity ranges from −1 meaning exactly opposite, to 1
 * meaning exactly the same, with 0 usually indicating independence, and
 * in-between values indicating intermediate similarity or dissimilarity.
 * 
 * For text matching, the attribute vectors A and B are usually the term
 * frequency vectors of the documents. The cosine similarity can be seen as
 * a method of normalizing document length during comparison.
 * 
 * In the case of information retrieval, the cosine similarity of two
 * documents will range from 0 to 1, since the term frequencies (tf-idf
 * weights) cannot be negative. The angle between two term frequency vectors
 * cannot be greater than 90°.
 * 
 * @param leftVector
 * @param rightVector
 * @return
 */
private static double consineVectorSimilarity(int[] leftVector,
        int[] rightVector) {
    if (leftVector.length != rightVector.length)
        return 1;
    double dotProduct = 0;
    double leftNorm = 0;
    double rightNorm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < leftVector.length; i++) {
        dotProduct += leftVector[i] * rightVector[i];
        leftNorm += leftVector[i] * leftVector[i];
        rightNorm += rightVector[i] * rightVector[i];
    }

    double result = dotProduct
            / (Math.sqrt(leftNorm) * Math.sqrt(rightNorm));
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String left[] = { "Julie", "loves", "me", "more", "than", "Linda",
            "loves", "me" };
    String right[] = { "Jane", "likes", "me", "more", "than", "Julie",
            "loves", "me" };
    System.out.println(consineTextSimilarity(left,right));
}
}
```

Comment: if you can modify the program please please help me because I need it too but to calculate the similarity between 2 words or more I tried but it kept giving me 0, this one calculate the similarity between 2 sentences .